# Commutative Ring Epimorphism on quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$,$J$ be ideals of $R$.

Define $f: R \rightarrow R/I \times R/J$ as $f(a) = (a+I,a+J)$.

Prove that if $f$ homomorphism is surjective, then $I+J = R$.

..

I think $\gcd([R:I],[R:J])$ must be 1.

I've found Ker$f$ = $I \cap J$ and tried first isomorphism theorem but could not go any further.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've found Ker$f$ = $I \cap J$ and tried first isomorphism theorem but could not go any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is surjective then, for any $(a+I,b+J) \in R/I\times R/J$, there exists some $c \in R$ such that $f(c) = (a+I,b+J)$, i.e.
$$
(c+I,c+J) = (a+I,b+J)
$$
Applying this $((a+1)+I,a+J)$ we get that there exists $c \in R$ such that
$$
(c+I,c+J) = ((a+1)+I,a+J)
$$
Applying the coset criterion, this implies that $a+1-c \in I$ and that $c-a \in J$, so we have that
$$
(a+1-c) + (c-a) = 1 \in I + J
$$
Thus $I$ and $J$ are relatively prime, so $I+J = R$ as desired.

Comment: Non-surjective epimorphisms do exist, such as the inclusion of the integers into the rationals.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang this is a good point, OP edited their original post to be surjective instead of epimorphism

Answer (score 2):

Remember that epimorphisms need not be surjective (consider $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, for example).

In general, $R \to S \times T$ is an epimorphism if and only if $R \to S$ and $R \to T$ are epimorphisms and $S \otimes_{R} T=0$.

In particular, $R \to R/I \times R/J$ is (*a priori* possibly non-surjective) epimorphism iff $(R/I) \otimes_{R} (R/J)=0$ iff $R/(I+J)=0$ iff $I+J=R$.

The Chinese Remainder Theorem then implies that $R \to R/I \times R/J$ will in fact be surjective if $I+J=R$.

Comment: that was my fault, edited as "if f homomorphism is surjective...". thanks <3